# When is the memory for a category released if you make a category over a singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

If I write a singleton class in Objective C and I make multiple categories over it.

Now if I #import any category into a class, when will be the memory for the category be released?

Will it be released with the object in which it is imported or will it be released when the app is terminated since its written over a singleton object?

I logically feel it should be removed with the object's memory deallocation. But I still want to be sure if I'm correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

There's no memory allocation involved when using categories, since you cannot add any properties this way.

As for singleton objects, you are correct. Their allocations are released when the app terminates.

Comment: Well there is a provision to add properties to a category. Which is what makes me wonder of when exactly is the memory from the objects released.

Comment: Can you link to what you're referring to?